# scikit-learn normalizer.fit() memory error

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I am trying to normalize my dataset before transforming it using dict vectorizer here. Though i have 244GB memory in my machine, I keep getting this Memory error when i normalize the data. Here is my code snippet,

X is my feature data.

```
# Normalizer that will normalize the data
normalizer = Normalizer().fit(X)
```

Error:-

```
File "train_models.py", line 336, in splittingdata
    normalizer = Normalizer().fit(X)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py", line 1426, in fit
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr')
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 407, in check_array
    _assert_all_finite(array)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 56, in _assert_all_finite
    and not np.isfinite(X).all()):
MemoryError
```

And the size of the data set is 560000 rows with 23 columns

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           240G        563M        238G        8.6M        979M        238G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

Here is my python architecture.

```
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:09:15) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import platform
>>> import sys
>>> platform.architecture(), sys.maxsize
(('64bit', 'ELF'), 9223372036854775807)


####Here is my code.

def splittingdata(X,Y):

    # Split X and Y into training and testing sets
    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33)

    # Normalizer that will normalize the data
    normalizer = Normalizer().fit(X)

    # Normalized Features:
    X_norm = normalizer.transform(X)

    # Split X and Y into training and testing sets for normalized data
    X_norm_train, X_norm_test, Y_norm_train, Y_norm_test = train_test_split(X_norm, Y, test_size=0.33)

    # Store Normalizer
    joblib.dump(normalizer, '../models/normalizer.pkl')

    actualdata = list([X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test])
    normalizeddata = list([X_norm_train, X_norm_test, Y_norm_train, Y_norm_test])

    return list([actualdata,normalizeddata])



def data_encoding(data):

    # Build X and Y
    # X : Features
    # Y : Target

    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    print "Start time of data encoding : ", start_time

    # Removing id column (listing_id)
    datav1 = data.drop(['id'], axis = 1)

    # Taking out the numeric columns separately
    numeric_cols = ['list','of','numeric','columns']
    #x_numeric = datav1[ numeric_cols ].as_matrix()
    x_numeric = datav1[ numeric_cols ]

    # Constructing list of dictionaries (one dictionary for each column) to use dictvectorizer
    cat_cols = ['list','of','categorical','columns']
    cat_dict = datav1[ cat_cols ].to_dict( orient = 'records' )

    # The DictVectorizer converts data from a dictionary to an array
    vectorizer = DictVectorizer()

    # Convert X to Array
    x_categorical = vectorizer.fit_transform(cat_dict).toarray()

    # Combining numeric and categorical data
    X = np.hstack(( x_numeric, x_categorical ))

    # Store Vectorizer
    joblib.dump(vectorizer, '../models/vectorizer.pkl')

    # Taking out the target variable
    Y = datav1.target_col

    outdata = list([X,Y])

    end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    print "End time of data encoding : ", end_time

    total_time = end_time - start_time
    print "Total time taken for data encoding : ", total_time

    return outdata


def main():

    #Reading the preprocessed data
    processed_data = pd.read_csv('../data/data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8',index_col=0)

    #processed_data = processed_data.head(5)

    #Encoding dataset
    encoded_data = data_encoding(processed_data)

    #Splitting dataset
    splitted_data = splittingdata(encoded_data[0], encoded_data[1])
    actualdata = splitted_data[0]
    normalizeddata = splitted_data[1]

    output = runmodels(actualdata,normalizeddata)
```

As suggested in the comments, I tried to do garbage collection like this,
Added this snippet at the end of encoding_data function,

```
#Garbage collection
del x_numeric
del x_categorical
del cat_dict
del datav1
gc.collect()
```

Similarly added this in my main function before calling splittingdata funciton,

```
del processed_data
gc.collect()
```

What i noticed is, my memory spikes 100% when the vectorizer runs, then once it is done, not sure why it is not coming down even with garbage collection, it comes down to 47%, then normalizer increases it to 100% and fails. So if i refactor the code as suggested in the answer, still the problem will remain i think. Is there a way to find out which object is holding most memory in runtime?

Comment: check the free memory before you run the code, maybe some other process is taking the space (run free -h if you are on a linux machine)

Comment: I did that, its almost free. Updated the question.

Comment: What is `X` exactly? What version of Python are you on? Is your Python 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: show a larger snippet of your code, maybe there are some unecessary duplication of the data else where. Also when you no longer need some variable, remove it with `del`

Comment: Updated my python architecture details. Let me update the question with some more code.

Comment: @MedAli Update the question with my code.

Comment: @ds_user check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

In `splittingdata(..)` you are loading and splitting the data twice. First load in here:

```
# Split X and Y into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33)
```

And the second in here:

```
# Split X and Y into training and testing sets for normalized data
X_norm_train, X_norm_test, Y_norm_train, Y_norm_test = train_test_split(X_norm, Y, test_size=0.33)
```

Remove the first train_test_split line and keep it like this:

```
# Normalizer that will normalize the data
normalizer = Normalizer().fit(X)

# Normalized Features:
X_norm = normalizer.transform(X)

# Split X and Y into training and testing sets for normalized data
X_norm_train, X_norm_test, Y_norm_train, Y_norm_test = train_test_split(X_norm, Y, test_size=0.33)
```

The function should look like this after the edit:

```
def splittingdata(X,Y):

    # Normalizer that will normalize the data
    normalizer = Normalizer().fit(X)

    # Normalized Features:
    X_norm = normalizer.transform(X)

    # Split X and Y into training and testing sets for normalized data
    X_norm_train, X_norm_test, Y_norm_train, Y_norm_test = train_test_split(X_norm, Y, test_size=0.33)

    # Store Normalizer
    joblib.dump(normalizer, '../models/normalizer.pkl')

    actualdata = list([X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test])
    normalizeddata = list([X_norm_train, X_norm_test, Y_norm_train, Y_norm_test])

    return list([actualdata,normalizeddata])
```

---

If you want to keep both you need to refactor your code as follows:

1. make the function `splittingdata(..)` generic to support splitting `actual_data` and `normalized_data` independently.
2. Update your `main(..)`:
   You need to consider refactoring the code so that It calls the model/models seperately for `actual_data` and `normalized_data` and combine the output at the end, something like this:

   ```
    def main():
       #Reading the preprocessed data
       processed_data = pd.read_csv('../data/data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8',index_col=0) 
       #processed_data = processed_data.head(5) 
       #Encoding dataset
       encoded_data = data_encoding(processed_data)
       X,Y = encoded_data[0], encoded_data[1]
       #Splitting dataset
       # non normalized 
       actualdata = splittingdata(X,Y)

       # run only on actualdata 
       output1 = runmodels(actualdata)

       # Normalizer that will normalize the data
       normalizer = Normalizer().fit(X)

       # Normalized Features:
       X_norm = normalizer.transform(X)
       normalizeddata = splittingdata(X_norm, Y)

       output2 = runmodels(normalizeddata)

       # combine output1 and output2 here
   ```

Comment: But I want both. One split with actual data and another one with normalized data. Because I am training one multiple models, some will use normalized and some without normalization. How to get this? - actualdata = list([X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test]) without actual split.

Comment: @ds_user you will need to refactor your code and think differently on how to accomplish what you want.. check my edit I added some suggestions. I hope this helps !